# How to deal with SSL Certs to invoke https service in Jar (Spring Batch) Applications

Tags: java, spring, ssl, ssl-certificate, spring-batch

In my application i need to make https call from a batch app (jar).

In order to make sucessfull service call, I definetly need to install certs related to the end point which am pointing to.

How can we install SSL certs and use the same inorder to invoke HTTPS service securely from stand alone jar application (where there is no server involved)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to import is create bean in your spring configuration file for below class

```
   <bean id="certLoad" class="com.kp.LoadHttpsCertificate">
       <property key="password" value="password"/>
       <property key="keyfile" value="absolute file path"/>
   </bean>
```

LoadHttpsCertificate .java

```
public class LoadHttpsCertificate {


    private  String password;
    private  String keyfile;


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getKeyfile() {
        return keyfile;
    }
    public void setKeyfile(String keyfile) {
        this.keyfile = keyfile;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadFile(){

        //System.out.println("setting property javax.net.ssl.trustStore = " + keyfile);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyfile);

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",password);
        //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "jks");
        //System.setProperty("org.jboss.security.ignoreHttpsHost", "true");

        Properties pi = System.getProperties();
        pi.put("file.encoding", "UTF-8"); // To add a new one
        System.setProperties(pi);

    }



}
```

Though I would prefer to load the certificate by importing to java's security directory(please refer the [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/add-list-certficates-java-keystore.html) for more details)